# Extracting words of a vector with names

Tags: r, regex, string

This is my vector:

```
m.v<- c("Aert~Derr", "Aert~Derr", "Aert~Derr", "Aert~Derr", 
    "Aert~Derr", "Aert~Derr", "Aert~Derr", "Aert~Derr", "Aert~Derr")
```

How can I create another vector with only the first name before the `~`?

So, how can I extract the first names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways of doing this. Here is a base R option using `sub`

```
sub("~\\w+", "", m.v)
[1] "Aert" "Aert" "Aert" "Aert" "Aert" "Aert" "Aert" "Aert" "Aert"
```

or using `strsplit`

```
sapply(strsplit(m.v, "~"), "[[", 1)
[1] "Aert" "Aert" "Aert" "Aert" "Aert" "Aert" "Aert" "Aert" "Aert"
```

Comment: Evers I edited the questions. I need to extract the words

Comment: @DiogoBastos I edited my answer. For the regexp's just replace `[A-Z]` with `\\w+`.

Answer (score 2):

Here you have some other alternatives:

```
> gsub("~.*$", "", m.v)
[1] "Aert" "Aert" "Aert" "Aert" "Aert" "Aert" "Aert" "Aert" "Aert"


> library(stringr)
> str_extract(m.v, "^\\w+")
[1] "Aert" "Aert" "Aert" "Aert" "Aert" "Aert" "Aert" "Aert" "Aert"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another example that will even work if you have more than one letter before the `~`:

```
gsub('(.*)~.*', '\\1', m.v)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `word` function from `stringr` and mention the `sep`arator explicitly.

```
library(stringr)
word(m.v, sep = "~")
#[1] "Aert" "Aert" "Aert" "Aert" "Aert" "Aert" "Aert" "Aert" "Aert"
```